# Build a javascript sliding puzzle

Tags: createjs

I am attempting to build a game that follows the same mechanic as Dragon's Tail featured at the following link http://bit.ly/1CR0iha. I have built a very basic version of level one working using mouse clicks with one open space. I really want it to move on pressmove so that I can drag the pieces to move them rather than on click which will help when there are more than one open space as on level two.

How to confine the movement of the pieces so that they can ONLY move into the open space? My initial though was to place all the pieces into a grid and check for collisions between the various pieces on pressmove and only allow a move if there is no collision.

After some coding I need a sanity check because I am now second guessing my decision. I am asking for on a high level sanity check on my method any insights are most welcome ;);

[image]

Once I have set my x and y on mousedown I them do the following on pressmove. I am not limiting my direction which is what I am trying to achieve.

```
 pressMove = function(event){
    var pt = this.globalToLocal(event.stageX, event.stageY);
    if(pt.x > this.startPosX){
        this.dragDirection = 'right';
    }

    if(pt.x < this.startPosX){
        this.dragDirection = 'left';
    }

    if(pt.y < this.startPosY){
        this.dragDirection = 'up';
    }

    if(pt.y > this.startPosY){
        this.dragDirection = 'down';
    }

    movePiece(event);
}
```

Moving the piece

```
 movePiece = function(event){
    var obj = event.target;
    var pt = this.globalToLocal(event.stageX, event.stageY);

    switch(this.dragDirection){
        case 'up':
            obj.y = pt.y;
            break;
        case 'down':
            obj.y = pt.y;
            break;
        case 'left':
            obj.x = pt.x;
            break;
        case 'right':
            obj.x = pt.x;
            break;
    };
}
```

Comment: as far as I understand your code you're resetting the movement direction on **every** mouse move, correct? in that case you should move the decision, which direction to pick, into the click-event, then keep that direction for the duration of the movement. if you want to change direction during movement, you should look into projecting points onto a polyline.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios thanks again for taking the time on this. I have a version working on click with only one available space on the board. There is only ever one option so the direction is easy to set but how would I get the direction on mousedown if there are multiple open spaces and the user can choose which one?

Comment: in that case you snap to the nearest axis at the center of a piece to allow the user to change his dragging direction, but outside this *deadzone* snap to the axis that the user last selected and allow drag only along this axis. again: look at projecting onto polylines. there is no one solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need sofisticated collision detection - all you need to know is which are the possible moves (up, down, right, left) allowed for a clicked piece.

you can do this by having a 2d field representing *blocked* spaces `1` and *free* spaces `0` like so

```
  A B C D
X 1 0 1 1
Y 1 1 1 1
Z 1 1 1 1
```

say you click the piece (Y,B) you can see by checking its four neighbouring entries that only the move *up* is available, similarly for XA and XC. for all other pieces there are no free spaces and thus no possible moves. after moving a piece, make sure its again in a grid position and update the 2d field. i.e. after moving YB *up* the field should look like this:

```
  A B C D
X 1 1 1 1
Y 1 0 1 1
Z 1 1 1 1
```

you can make boundary handling easier by surrounding your actual playfield with *blocked* spaces

**Edit**: say you only move up/down and left/right. Every *move* starts at the center of a piece. Around the center there's a *deadzone* where it's not clear (yet) which direction the move will take. Then your code might look like this:

```
startDrag(x, y) {
    // remember clicked piece p
    p <- ...
    // remember center positions for p (cX, cY)
    (cX, cy) <- ...
    // remember offset of cursor to center (oX, oY)
    (oX, oY) <- (x - cX, y - cY)
}

continueDrag(x, y) {
    // select move direction
    if distance between (cX, cY) and (x - oX, y - oY) is within the deadzone
        select move direction (up, down, left, right) with least projection error
    else
        select last move direction
    end
    // get constrained move direction
    switch selected move direction
        case up: perform move to (cX, y - oY)
        case down: perform move to (cX, y - oY)
        case left: perform move to (x - oX, cY)
        case right: perform move to (y - oX, cY)
    end
}
```

you can see all of this in action (and a bit more robust) here: http://js.do/code/sliding-puzzle

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I currently have a 'grid' array where I store the x y and occupied parameters. I then have a function where I getNeighbors() and based on which tile you click it returns an array of its neighbors. ie clicking tile 'TL' would return - [                     {pos:'t',x:186,y:0,occupied:false},{pos:'ml',x:0,y:134,occupied:false}]. if a tile existed in those position then occupied would equal 'true'. When the tile is moved I update the parameters to the new values. My problem how to confine the pieces movement on 'pressmove'

Comment: @non_tech_guy constrain the movement: if you only ever have 1 free space, simply only accept movement in the direction (to and from) of the piece and the free space. if you may have several free spaces project the movement onto the possible axis (up/down or right/left) and accept the move for the smallest projection error.

Comment: how I have tried this is that on press I set up two start variables , x and y. Then on pressmove I update a variable dragDirection. The piece still moves diagonally.

Comment: more detail added to the initial question which includes pressmove function.

Comment: @non_tech_guy please post your code for moving the piece too

Comment: I have updated the question. The result is that the pieces slides on the y axis but on the x.

Comment: @non_tech_guy I extended my answer considerably, tell me if you are still unclear

Comment: thanks for the update, it is greatly appreciated. I will have a look and let you know ;)